# Oracle - Left Anti Join on same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a Oracle DB which contains several columns. Two of them contains different booking numbers. "Key1" and "Key2". If "Key2" contains a number (<>0) then this is declared as a correction. So the same number on "Key1" is obselet - should be deleted.

I think a join is the perfect way - or a elegant way - to delete the corrections bookings and the respective "Key1".

How can I implement a "Left Anti Join" into this code:

```
SELECT
    replace(to_char("Start", '00,00,00'),',',':') as "tStart",
    "Key1" as "Key1",
    "Key2" as "Key2",
    "Value" as "Value",
    "Date" as "Date",
    "Dep" as "Dep"
FROM "POOL112"."IKZ99H"
WHERE   "Value" >950
    AND "Dep" = 1
```

Or do you have a more appropriate solution/ idea?

Comment: "...Key1 is obsolete, should be deleted..." - Do you mean it should be updated with a null value? Or do you mean the whole row should be deleted from the table? Or the whole row to just be removed from the `SELECT` result?

Comment: Thanks! The last one. The row with "Key2" and the respective "Key" row should be removed from the select result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following query will "filter out" the rows you don't want to show:

```
with
x as (
  select key1, key2 from pool112.ikz99h where key2 <> 0
)
select * -- all my columns here
from pool112.ikz99h
where value > 950 
  and dep = 1
  and key1 not in (select key1 from x) -- filtering out obsolete rows
  and key2 not in (select key2 from x) -- filtering out superseding rows
```

Comment: Thanks! I am gona try this in a few minutes. But what is about a join? Is your approach more performant/ efficient? I thought joins are appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0):

So that Key1 should not exist as a Key2 in another record?

```
SELECT
REPLACE(TO_CHAR("Start", '00,00,00'),',',':') as "tStart",
Key1, Key2, "Value", "Date", Dep
FROM "POOL112"."IKZ99H" t
WHERE "Value" > 950
  AND Dep = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
      SELECT *
      FROM "POOL112"."IKZ99H" d
      WHERE d.Key2 = t.Key1
        AND d.Key1 <> d.Key2
  )
```

Or by using a LEFT JOIN with a NULL check.

```
SELECT
REPLACE(TO_CHAR(t."Start", '00,00,00'),',',':') as "tStart",
t.Key1, t.Key2, t."Value", t."Date", t.Dep
FROM "POOL112"."IKZ99H" t
LEFT JOIN "POOL112"."IKZ99H" d ON (d.Key2 = t.Key1 AND d.Key1 <> d.Key2)
WHERE t."Value" > 950
  AND t.Dep = 1
  AND d.Key2 IS NULL
```

Comment: So, the Key1 contains numbers from 66000-99000. The Key2 contains either a 0 or a number between 66000-99000. If Key2 contains 66001 and Key1 contains 66001 both rows have to be deleted/ filtered. I think your code do not manage/ aim this, right`?

Comment: @joshua1990 These Sql's will discard only the records where same the Key1 is found in the Key2 of another record. Because of that `ON (d.Key2 = t.Key1 AND d.Key1 <> d.Key2)`. That's how I understood this programming puzzle. But as you explain it, then that rule could be changed to `ON (d.Key2 = t.Key1 OR d.Key1 = t.Key2)` to discard both.